# How can I check if the input has coordinates or the name of a place?

Tags: java, string, int

I have the following issue: I have to ask the user to introduce a String. This String is it going to be a place name (for example, Spain) or the coordinates of the place (for example: `4.268482, 6.162849`).

How can I check if it's a coordinate or a name? I've tried creating a for a clause that iterates till it founds a comma (,) but also the place name can contain commas (for example, `Barcelona, Spain`).

How can I solve this efficiently?

Comment: Sounds like it would be fairly easy to check using a regular expression - have you tried that?

Comment: What if it neither the one nor the other? Can the name contain blanks? Non-ascii characters? Please be precise.

Comment: you can use a regular expression

Comment: Apply a regex to check if its the format of two numbers separated by a comma. You can also try to split on comma and then attempt to parse both values `Double.parseDouble`, if it fails, its a location (or neither).

Answer (score 1):

Since OP is unresponsive, I assume that names of places are allowed to contain all characters, including blanks and non-ascii characters like Kanjis and the likes. Thus, everything is a place name.

Since everything is a place-name, one should first check whether the `String` passed are two floating-point numbers, separated by a comma and a blank. For this, one could use the following regular expression:

```
^-?(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:.\d*[0-9])?, -?(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:.\d*[0-9])?$
```

[<kbd>regex101 demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/txUCm0/1/)

Notice that this regular expression does not checkf or a legal range of the GPS coordinates.

If the given `String` does not match this regular expression, it would be a place-name.

A sample program may look like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Ideone {
    public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^-?(?:[1-9]\\d*|0)" +
            "(?:.\\d*[0-9])?, -?(?:[1-9]\\d*|0)(?:.\\d*[0-9])?$");

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isGpsCoordinate("0.0, 0.0"));
        System.out.println(isGpsCoordinate("New York"));
        System.out.println(isGpsCoordinate("東京"));
    }

    private static boolean isGpsCoordinate(final String input) {
        return PATTERN.matcher(input).matches();
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rlmlKT)

Answer (score -2):

I recomends to use a regex to identify the word only has number.

```
  /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class as {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
        String word = "4.268482, 6.162849";
        String[] it = word.split(",");
        for (String it1 : it) {
            if (pattern.matcher(it1).matches()) {
                System.out.println("Numerico");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Texto");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a quick regex-demo. But it does not apply to OPs question, he needs two floating numbers separated by comma. It would be more helpful if you show a pattern that matches this.

Comment: What if the place name is `"New York"`? Or `"東京"`?

Comment: @zabuza , I changed the code to ask the question